# Mapping individual elements in a Stream<Collection<T>>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

When working with a `Stream<Collection<T>>`, I would like to apply the usual methods from the Java 8 Stream API to every element of type T in every collection in my stream. As the title states, I mainly want to map the elements, but of course all the other methods (e.g. `filter(Predicate)` or `allMatch(Predicate)`) are of interest as well.

Consider the example of a 2D board storing multiple rectangle tiles. Each tile is defined by the (x, y)-positions it occupies on the board.

```
List<Position> tile1 = Lists.asList(tile1Pos1, tile1Pos2, ...)
List<Position> tile2 = Lists.asList(tile2Pos1, tile2Pos2, ...)
...
List<List<Position>> board = Lists.asList(tile1, tile2, ...)
```

When rotating the board, I want to convert all the positions of the tiles. I need to apply the same x to y and y to x mapping function to every position. However, I have to retain the association between the tiles and their respective positions.

Currently, I am doing the following with my `Stream<List<Position>> streamOfCollections`:

```
List<List<Position>> rotatedBoard = board.stream().map(tile -> tile.stream().map(Position::mapperFunctionRotate).collect(toList())).collect(toList());
```

Note that I am retaining the original layout of my data. Each position is still associated to the one specific tile it is a part of.

Generalizing, for any `Stream<Collection<T>>` I want to modify all the individual elements of type T while keeping them in their collection.
Ideally, I would like to be able to do `board.stream().mapIndividually(Position::mapperFunctionRotate)` which has a similar method signature as `flatMap` in the Java Stream API, but **does not flatten** my stream of lists.

**Are there any convenient ways to simplify the above mapping function?**

I am also looking for libraries or frameworks which get the job done. As it seems to me that the Java API does not support such a thing, other libraries are actually the main scope of this question, I think.

I already looked at *guava* which offers data structures like `Multimap<K, V>` behaving like a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, but I had no luck finding extensions for/of the Java Stream API.

Comment: You could modify `mapperFunctionRotate` to accept a `Collection`.

Comment: Did you looked into [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) ?

Comment: @Spotted Thanks, I have now looked at the functionalities it offers. The aim of this question can be achieved with an `EntryStream`, but that solution would not be shorter nor more readable than vanilla Java. In fact, one would have to assign each collection a key (most likely integer) and then create the "flat" entry stream. The difference being that - contrary to just a flat collection - each value has an associated key specifying which former collection it was a part of. Then, my mapping function could be applied to each value, leaving the keys unchanged. Finally, convert back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear what you are aiming at. The solution you have shown *is* already the canonical solution. If you want to do similar things repeatedly, you may abstract it into a method:

```
public static <T,R> List<List<R>> applyToAll(
    Collection<? extends Collection<? extends T>> source,
    Function<? super T, ? extends R> op) {

    return source.stream()
        .map(c -> c.stream().map(op).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

which you can use in your specific case as

```
List<List<Position>> rotatedBoard = applyToAll(board, Position::mapperFunctionRotate);
```

Generally, there is no shortcut for “convert every element of a collection and produce a collection”, hence, there is also no shortcut for the same thing in a nested context.

Of course, you could create your own and implement the nested variant atop:

```
public static <T,R> List<R> mapAll(
    Collection<T> source, Function<? super T, ? extends R> op) {
    return source.stream().map(op).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

…

```
List<List<Position>> rotatedBoard
    = mapAll(board, l -> mapAll(l, Position::mapperFunctionRotate));
```

If you think, it doesn’t feel FP enough, you could declare it as

```
public static <T,R,C extends Collection<T>>
    Function<C, List<R>> mapAll(Function<? super T, ? extends R> op) {
    return source -> source.stream().map(op).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

to be used like

```
Function<List<List<Position>>,List<List<Position>>> f
    = mapAll(mapAll(Position::mapperFunctionRotate));
List<List<Position>> rotatedBoard = f.apply(board);
```

unfortunately, Java requires an explicit declaration of the function type here, otherwise, `mapAll(mapAll(Position::mapperFunctionRotate)).apply(board)` would make a great use case, especially as it would be easy to extend to more dimensions. But Java’s (current) type inference can’t deal with that.

You can, however, combine both `mapAll` methods above to

```
List<List<Position>> rotatedBoard = mapAll(board, mapAll(Position::mapperFunctionRotate));
```

Comment: When working with map-like data which needs multiple values for each key, then `Map<K, Collection<V>>`would also be the canonical way of implementing that. Yet, guava has created an easier solution which yields more readable code and is additionally lots more efficient than the vanilla Java solution. So I was thinking that maybe there exists a library already, extending the Java Streams API in a similar manner. But apparently, there isn't. Thanks a lot for the `mapAll()` methods! I'd prefer using it like `board.stream().map(mapAll(Position::mapperFunctionRotate)).collect(toList())`.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you looking for flatmap here?

```
 .stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I didn't think so, because `flatMap(T::mapToFoo)` does not retain my collection of collections structure. After all I don't want a list of all my elements but rather have them grouped into seperate sub-lists so to speak.

Comment: @1Darco1 yup, I've re-read the question, you want to preserve the initial layout. Sill can't really tell what you want to simply here?